# Windows installation disk MBR error

Tags: mbr, windows-installation

I need to install windows on a laptop which has no OS. When selecting the partition of Hard disk to install... Gives me such an error:"Windows cannot be installed to this disk. the selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI systems windows can only be installed to GPT disk." Please get me out of here!

Answer (score 0):

Either You have to disable EFI boot and install Windows on MBR or You have to convert partition scheme to GPT and use EFI boot.

It seems like if you have enabled UEFI boot in BIOS, windows will allow you to install it only on a GPT drive. You can disable EFI boot from BIOS and then install on MBR partition.